# how to draw group histogram graph and add trend line in R?

Tags: r

[example graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LVLZ7.png)

As picture shows above, I have data like

```
year  0-19years_old   20-44years_old  45-64years_old  above_65years old
2000   20000             34000            29000           16700
2005   19800             33000            28500           17000
```

I would like to draw the each age group separately histogram graph in r, and the x present year, y present count. It will be great if use different color for each histogram and give note in the side to say which color present what age group. Also draw another linear graph shows how each age group change for two years, here should be 4 lines in different color but in one graph.

Thanks for all help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is a bar chart not a histogram.

1. Bring your data into long format with `pivot_longer`
2. use `geom_bar()` for the bar chart
3. `geom_line()` for line chart
4. library(cowplot) to plot both plots side by side

```
library(tidyverse)
library(cowplot)

df1 <- df %>% 
  pivot_longer(
    cols = ends_with("old"),
    names_to = "names",
    values_to = "values"
  ) 

a <- ggplot(df1, aes(x=factor(year), y=values, fill=names)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity", position = "dodge") + 
  geom_text(aes(label=values), vjust=1.6, color="black",
            position = position_dodge(0.9), size=3.5)+
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Set1")

b <- ggplot(df1, aes(x=factor(year), y=values, color=names, group=names)) +
  geom_point() + 
  geom_line() +
  scale_color_brewer(palette = "Set1")

plot_grid(a, b, labels = "AUTO")
```

[image]

data:

```
df <- tribble(
~year,  ~`0-19years_old`,   ~`20-44years_old`,  ~`45-64years_old`,  ~`above_65years_old`, 
2000,   20000,             34000,            29000,           16700,
2005,   19800,            33000,           28500,           17000)
```

Comment: thanks for answering! but I got the error like below:
Error: `cols` must select at least one column.
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.

Comment: The error occurs because of the name of your columns: 1. Do not start a column name with numbers. 2. Do not use special characters like %$ etc.. in column names. 3. Do not use space in column names. If you have to use all these then set the colname in back ticks. Some of your colnames start with number, some use special character and the most important the last column name has a space -> potentially creating a character column with NA. Please see my edit with your column names how it should work. But I suggest to change the column names.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyr)

dat <- tibble::tribble(
  ~year,  ~`0-19`,   ~`20-44`,  ~`45-64`, ~`65+`,
  2000,   20000,             34000,            29000,           16700,
  2005,   19800,             33000,            28500,           17000
) |> 
  pivot_longer(
    cols = -year,
    names_to = "age_group",
    values_to = "count"
  )
dat
#> # A tibble: 8 x 3
#>    year age_group count
#>   <dbl> <chr>     <dbl>
#> 1  2000 0-19      20000
#> 2  2000 20-44     34000
#> 3  2000 45-64     29000
#> 4  2000 65+       16700
#> 5  2005 0-19      19800
#> 6  2005 20-44     33000
#> 7  2005 45-64     28500
#> 8  2005 65+       17000

# Grouped bar chart
ggplot(dat) +
  aes(x = year, y = count, fill = age_group) +
  geom_col(position = "dodge")
```

[image]

```r
# Line chart
ggplot(dat) +
  aes(x = year, y = count, color = age_group) +
  geom_line()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-05-30 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

The key ideas are:

1. Organize your data with the variables in columns.
2. Map age group to `fill` and/or `color` in the plot
3. Set `position = "dodge"` in `geom_col()` for the grouped bar chart